# Can someone help me figure out the name of a sci-fi book about space travel at the speed of light?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, space, hard-sci-fi, space-exploration

I read this book when I was much younger and can't remember the name of it but I remember it's one of the best books I've ever read.

It starts with this young girl that bumps into an older lady, the lady introduces herself as "Alpha". Later the young girl goes on a space mission where she will be traveling at the speed of light orbiting around the Earth. After many years, during which time she sees the earth come to an end and be reborn, she even sees history repeating itself, she ends up landing the space craft that she's been on. The books ends with her coming out of a building and bumping into a young girl and introducing herself as Alpha. (History repeated itself).

If there's anyway anyone can help me figure out the name of this book so I can try to get it that would be great. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Not an answer, but does [this description](http://www.sffchronicles.co.uk/forum/22685-whats-the-name-and-author-of-this-book.html) sound familiar?

Comment: Welcome to [SciFi.StackExchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) Claudia. We here will do our best to try and identify the story you're looking for, however, we unfortunately do not know how old you are, which makes quantifying the statement "when I much younger" very difficult. If you could update your question with the approximate year or decade that you read this book it may help us out a lot. Thank you, and again, welcome to the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The link Wikis posted in the comments led me to the book [The Starlight Crystal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671550292). While I am unable to find a reputable plot synopsis of any detail I did find one [here](http://www.angelfire.com/moon2/starlightcrystal/pages/plot.html) which hopefully will help you out. For your convenience I have also copied it below (mouse over the gray area to reveal the text).

> The Starlight Crystal is about a women named Paige Christian. She meets a guy named Tem and they fall in love but she has to leave to go into space on the spaceship "Traveller". The ship is made to travell so fast that one hour is equall to 10 years on Earth. Her father is the captain otherwise she would not go. The purpose of the trip is to watch mankind develop new things over the period of 2 million years. During the journey about 30 years in the Earth is destroyed by aliens. They then board the Traveller and her father is killed trying to destroy the ship. A alien helps them escape and then the creator helps them return to whats left of Earth. As they are returning she touches an alien and all her knowledge is passed to her. When they return the creator tells her to then steal the ship and drive to the end of the universe. She does then creation starts all over again. When she returns to Earth the Traveller is just leaving and she relises that she is a clone of herself. She then finds Tem and marries him. They have two children (although she never told Tem they're clones of themselves). After a while she relises that the aliens should soon attack them so using her supperior knowledge of spacecraft thanks to the alien she helps NASA build a spaceship that can freeze people and wake them up later. They launch the ship and while they are getting into the freezers she programs Tems to kill him. Then she programs hers to wake her up earlier that everyone else. When she wakes up she tells her children the fate of the Earth and tells them how to kill the aliens and where to find them. Then she kills herself. Her childen go and kill the alien but Tem Jr. was killed during the attack. Paige Jr. survived and lived happily ever after.

Comment: Hooooly crap, I was just googling trying to find this same book! I've been trying to hunt it down for years! THANK GAWWWWWD